# Inject query ID automatically with mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to inject query ID as a comment in SQL statement automatically to explain heavy queries.

e.g.

If there is a mapper class like this:

```
package com.example.mapper;

import com.example.domain.Blog;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

import java.util.List;

public interface BlogMapper {
    @Select("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=#{id}")
    List<Blog> findById(String id);
}
```

I want to send a query like

```
/* BlogMapper.findById */SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=5
```

Comment: Doesn't `@Select("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=#{id} --BlogMapper.findById")` work ?

Comment: Of course, it works. but I want to inject it by plugin or something.